# Command to get hard disk quota on linux

Tags: linux, command, quota

Is there any simple command to get total hard disk quota and total used on linux? I've been searched for a long time but cannot find. Is it 'df'?

Answer (score 1):

You have found the right command:
df

or

df -H

the last one with -H options will convert big numbers of bytes to, for example, Gbytes, which is convenient in some cases.